# Customize Modern Document Library New Form

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-document-library

Is it possible to customize the Document Library New form in Modern UI in SharePoint Online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Modern" lists and libraries do not support as many customization options as "classic" lists and libraries.

Currently, it is not supported to customize the default New Form in modern library.

[Customizing "modern" lists and libraries](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-lists-and-libraries)